# Generate data-confirm not working

Tags: yii2

I have this code in my gridview

```
....
[
                'label'=>'Read',
                'format' => 'html',
                'value'=>function ($data) {
                    return Html::a('Read',Url::to(['readmessage/read/','q'=>$data->message_id]), ['data' => ['confirm' => 'My confirm question here?']]);
                },
            ],
....
```

But above code is not generate data-confirm option in anchor link, and I have tried `[data-confirm => 'My confirm question here?']` not working too.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Check if `yii.js` is present in your rendered view file. In addition - you don't have to wrap route in `Url::to()` inside `Html::a()` - it's done automatically.

Comment: @Bizley yii.js is present

Comment: What if you change `format` to `raw`?

Comment: @Bizley thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the format to 'raw':

```
        [
            'label'=>'Read',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value'=>function ($data) {
                return Html::a('Read',Url::to(['readmessage/read/','q'=>$data->message_id]), ['data' => ['confirm' => 'My confirm question here?']]);
            },
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use "data-confirm"

```
        [
            'label'=>'Read',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value'=>function ($data) {
                return Html::a('Read',Url::to(['readmessage/read/','q'=>$data->message_id]), ['data-confirm' => 'My confirm question here?']);
            },
        ],
```